# Sending mail from PHP gives Unrouteable address

Tags: php, email, smtp, exim

I have a Debian server running PHP and Exim4 (among other things of course).
The PHP application is sending 1000s of emails every day all of which work fine, however I now have a new customer and my PHP/Exim4 has trouble sending to this account.

PS I added the --at-- to stop crawlers finding the addresses.

1. I checked the exim4 logs and found this:

> ```
> 2014-04-02 08:48:10 1WV7TW-0001Em-Od <= support --at-- sobs.com.au H=localhost [127.0.0.1] P=esmtp S=1215 
> 2014-04-02 08:48:11 1WV7TW-0001Em-Od ** az --at-- mentonegrammmar: Unrouteable address 
> 2014-04-02 08:48:11 1WV7TW-0001Em-Od Completed
> ```

2. I then checked the routing in exim4 using:

> ```
> # exim -bt az --at-- mentonegrammar
> R: dnslookup for az --at-- mentonegrammar
> az --at-- mentonegrammar
> router = dnslookup, transport = remote_smtp
> host mail.mentonegrammar [58.96.103.231] MX=5
> ```

This looks as though the routing is working perfectly.  I tried the application email again and still get the Unrouteable address error.

3. Then I tried a command line email from the same server.

   ```
   echo "Test message" | mail -s "Test message" az --at-- mentonegrammar
   ```

This email worked and arrived as required, but the email from my PHP application still fails.

4. I checked the application:

> ```
> $mime = new Mail_mime();
> $mime->setHTMLBody($body);
> $content = $mime->get(array('html_charset' => 'utf-8'));
> $formattedHeaders = $mime->headers($headers);
> $smtp = Mail::factory("smtp", array());
> $result = $smtp->send($headers["To"], $formattedHeaders, $content);
> ```

5. As mentioned there are 1000s of emails being successfully sent by this server and application.
6. The IT at Mentone Grammar haven't indicated any problems receiving any other emails.

In summary, I keep coming back to the 'Unrouteable address' error in the exim4 log, and the debug output indicating that the address is routable.  I can't help thinking there is some problem with the Exim4 config, yet only when getting the mail request from a PHP application, is it a security thing - I just don't know.

Can anybody point me in the right direction please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure, maybe a typo, but in one case you have three `mmm` (see exim4 logs) and in the other you have two `mm` (see your routing test and your `echo` test) in the domain name :

```
mentonegrammmar.net (does not exist)

mentonegrammar.net (exists)
```

Double-check for the correct domain name within your `PHP` application.

Comment: Thank you so much!  This was exactly the problem... and my browser kept remembering the incorrect entry and auto-filling the field without me noticing.